# C++ templated property in class header using std::map - Compiler error C1001

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, stdmap

I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my construct:

Struct

```
template<size_t N> struct Offsets 
{ 
    static const int length = N;
    DWORD offsets[N]; 
};
```

And the property:

```
template <size_t N>
std::map<std::string, std::map<DWORD, Offsets<N>>> pointers;
```

This results in a

> Compiler Error C1001.

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables can't be templated, they have to fully specified. So to declare your `pointers` variable you must specify the `N`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. thank you for the answer. Would you say using std::vector would be a better alternative?

Comment: @user2081200 I really can't say what would be best, as I don't really know what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Just a 3 dimensional mapping. like this: 1. Label, 2. Address, 3. Offsets. Offsets are not the same size, they vary.

Comment: @user2081200 Templates have to be fully evaluated at compilation, and it seems you want yo be able to have different sizes that are set during runtime. So yes, then a `std::vector` seems like a better solution.

Comment: @user2081200 It seems, you just want template/alias typedefs to use an arbitrary template instance of `struct Offsets` with the `std::map` template. This kind of typedef is already specified, but not yet supported everywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26151/1175253 (a workaround was just posted by DaBrain)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a template on a variable. If you want to keep pointers flexible encapsule it in a template class or struct.

```
template< size_t N >
class PointerOffsetMap
{
...
public:
    std::map<std::string, std::map<DWORD, Offsets<N>>> pointers;
}
```

just a very simple example, you should probably make pointers private and add some access functions to get a nice interface.