# Templated typedef workaround doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, c++03

I'm using C++03 (CUDA nvcc really, but that doesn't matter). I have the following bit of *working* code:

```
template<typename T> void baz(T*);

template<typename T>
void bar() {
    typedef void (*foo_t)(T*);
    static const foo_t dummy = baz;
    // use dummy
};
```

Now, I want to move the dummy variable out of the function, making it global.

**First attempt:**

```
template<typename T> void baz(T*);
template<typename T> typedef void (*foo_t)(T*);
template<typename T> const foo_t dummy = baz;

template<typename T>
void bar() {
    // use dummy
};
```

This doesn't work, since C++ (at least, C++03) doesn't have templated typedef:

> `error: "typedef" may not be specified here`
>
> `error: "foo_t" is not a function or static data member`

Why doesn't C++03 have this? Beats me.  If I can do it in a function, I can't see why I shouldn't be able to do it outside too. I think C++11 doesn't either (but there is the templated `using`, right?)

Ok, so I read [Template typedefs - What's your work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26151/1593077), and went for the accepted answer - using a helper class.

**Second Attempt:**

```
template<typename T> void baz(T*);
template<typename T> class TemplatingHeler {
  typedef void (*foo_t)(T*);
  static const foo_t dummy = baz;
}
```

... this gets:

> `error: a member of type "void (*const)(T *)" cannot have an in-class initializer`

**Third Attempt:**

```
template<typename T> void baz(T*);
template<typename T> class TemplatingHelper {
  typedef void (*foo_t)(T*);
  static foo_t dummy;
};
template<typename T> TemplatingHelper::dummy = baz;
```

> `error: name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name`
>
> `error: argument list for class template "TemplatingHelper" is missing`

... and nvcc segfaults (!)

Why does all this happen, and how can I get it to work?

Comment: You're using templates without template arguments. Anyway, the first is variable templates, which are right around the corner.

Comment: There's an alternative to templated typedefs: templated `using`. You should be using `using` (not to be confused with "you need to move it move it").

Comment: @stefan: Isn't templated `using` a feature of C++11? Anyway, can you give an example or link somewhere?

Comment: C++0x is the old name of C++11. The older standard is called C++03.

Comment: @einpoklum You're already using quasi-C++11. As n.m. said: it's only the preliminary name for C++11, if your compiler is reasonable up-to-date, `using` will be usable. Instead of `typedef int Foo;` you just write `using Foo = int;`. And for templates it's `template <typename T> Vector = std::vector<T>;`.

Comment: @stefan: I meant I'm using C++03 then. The previous standard. My compiler is actually NVidia CUDA nvcc...

Comment: The error you get might point to what's wrong with your code

Comment: Ooh, maybe I can help! What specific error are you getting?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Edited! Please do help! :-)

Comment: For the third attempt: `template<typename T> typename TemplatingHelper<T>::foo_t TemplatingHelper<T>::dummy = baz;`

Comment: @DyP: Please make that an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @einpoklum That's so sad. My condolences for beeing stuck with old C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third attempt should work, after fixing the errors ;)

```
template<typename T> void baz(T*);
template<typename T> class TemplatingHelper {
  typedef void (*foo_t)(T*);
  static foo_t dummy;
};

template<typename T>                   // template-declaration
typename TemplatingHelper<T>::foo_t    // type
TemplatingHelper<T>::dummy             // name
= baz;                                 // initializer
```

---

I agree it's redundant, but it follows a general form of declaration:

```
type name initializer ;
```

even though the name has already been declared and given a type inside the class template.

In this case, it's a template-declaration, so we need to add the `template<typename T>` part; this is required since we could also refer to a partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename U> class TemplatingHelper<T(*)(U)>
{
    typedef T(*foo_t)(U);
    static foo_t dummy;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
typename TemplatingHelper<T(*)(U)>::foo_t
TemplatingHelper<T(*)(U)>::dummy
= baz;
```

As the type is required and precedes the declared name, we need to explicitly state the scope where to find it:

```
TemplatingHelper<T>::foo_t
```

Unfortunately, name lookup requires to put a `typename` before this qualified name. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/420683)

Comment: That has got to be the most contrived piece of C++ code I've ever seen... why the @#$k do I need to specify the type of something that's already declared? And why do I need the `typename` keyword before the typename?

Comment: @einpoklum I've tried to explain it .. partially .. in the updated answer; in C++11 there are easier methods (besides the alias template = template typedef), for example `template<typename T> decltype(TemplatingHelper<T>::dummy) TemplatingHelper<T>::dummy = baz;` (simpler with macro), but I ran into compiler bugs using this.. thing. Also, `constexpr` allows to initialize `dummy` inside the class definition.

Comment: I don't understand why the initialization statement needs to be in the format of the declaration. `dummy` was already declared. Suppose `TemplatingHelper` was not a templated class and `dummy` was just an int. Would I not be able to initialize it with the statement `TemplatingHelper::dummy = 7`?

Comment: @einpoklum *"Would I not be able to initialize it with the statement"* No. The reason is that it's not just an initialization, but a *definition*. I.e. the statement also defines in which object file the variable is placed before linking. (From any other translation unit, it's referred to as an `extern` variable.) Being a definition, it's also a declaration itself (a redeclaration). Of course that's all just what it's *defined to be*. It might be more simple to parse as it's not a special case but just another definition. As I said, the compiler could infer the data type (-> `decltype`).